# Count yes and no answers in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel file with a few columns.  The columns have yes/no answers.  I would like to know the function to count all yes and no answers.

Thanks for helping an excel rookie.

Answer (score 12):

Use `COUNTIF`.

So if you have a column C with values 1 through 5 as follows:

```
1 - Yes
2 - No
3 - Yes
4 - No
5 - Yes
```

Formula would read:

```
=COUNTIF(C1:C5,"Yes")
```

This would output a result of `3`.

Comment: =COUNTIF(C1:C5;"Yes") the comma doesn't work for me. use the ; instead.

Comment: Should be marked as the answer